# How can I find a solution of second order ODE with variable coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find a solution of
$$
\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + (1+x^2)^{-1/2} \frac{d}{dx}  + c \right)f(x) = 0
$$
where $x \in \mathbb R$ and $c$ is a real constant.

Comment: [Variation of parameters.](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx)

Comment: Your best choice is power series technique.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I agree, but I'm wondering now if that $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}$ will be a problem.

Comment: It should not be a problem.

Comment: @M.Vinay The series at zero is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)}{2^n n!} x^{2n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Related techniques: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927901/is-there-a-closed-form-solution-for-this-differential-equation/932739#932739). Here is an approximate solution at the point $x=0$

> $$ f(x) \approx f(0)+f'(0)x-\frac{1}{2}(cf(0)+f'(0))x^2 . $$

You can obtain the above solution by assuming the solution has the form

> $$ f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x +a_2 x^2 + \dots $$

where

> $$  a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} .$$

To find $a_n$ use the given ode as

> $$ f''(x)= - (1+x^2)^{-1/2} f'(x)  - c f(x) . $$

You can differentiate the above equation to find higher derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for large positive $x$ the factor $(1+{x^2})^{-1/2}$ approaches $x^{-1}$ so $f$ approaches a Bessel function of order $0$. This seems to open a way to obtain an approximate solution for large $x>0$.